# Prove that if $d$ is a metric on a set $S$, then for any positive real number $c$ the product $c \cdot d$ is also a metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Prove that if $d$ is a metric on a set $S$, then for any positive real number $c$, the product $c \cdot d$ is also a metric.

Here I will use the notation $d_c$ to refer to the product $c \cdot d$.

Proof: Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space and $c \in (0, \infty)$.

First we show that for any $x,y \in S$, $d_c(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$. Let $x,y \in S$ such that $x=y$. Then since $d$ is a metric we have $d(x,y)=0$. Multiplying both sides by $c$, since we get $c \cdot d(x,y) = c \cdot 0 = 0$. Hence if $x=y$ then $d_c(x,y)=0$. Alternatively, if $x \neq y$ then we have $d(x,y) \neq 0$. Multiplying by $c$ we have $c \cdot d(x,y) \neq 0$ since $c \neq 0$. Hence if $x \neq y$ then $d_c(x,y) \neq 0$. Therefore $d_c(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$.

Next we show that for any $x,y \in S$, $d_c(x,y)=d_c(y,x)$. Since $d$ s a metric, we have that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ and multiplying by $c$ gives us $c \cdot d(x,y) = c \cdot d(y,x)$. Hence $d_c(x,y)=d_c(y,x)$, as desired.

Finally, we show that for any $x,y \in S$, $d_c(x,z) \leq d_c(x,y)+d_c(y,z)$. Since $d$ is a metric, we have $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Since $c>0$, multiplying by $c$ gives us $c \cdot d(x,z) \leq c \cdot d(x,y)+c \cdot d(y,z)$, as desired.

Conclude that $d_c$ is a metric on $S$. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. In general, you can try showing the following:

> Let $f : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ be an increasing subadditive function, i.e., $f(x + y) \leqslant f(x) + f(y)$. Further assume that $f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$. Then, given any metric $d : X \times X \to [0, \infty)$, the function $f \circ d$ is also a metric.